# What is meaning of big U in sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What does big U below signify? And what is number written above and below it?

[image]

Comment: When you have sets $X_1,X_2,\dots X_n$, then $$\bigcup\limits_{r=1}^n X_r=X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3\dots \cup X_n,$$ so it describes the union of all your given sets.

Comment: So answer should be 20 @Hirshy?

Comment: Answer to what? You mean to say that $n=20$? Then how did you get to that solution?

Comment: @Hirshy I deduced that no of elements in S must be 10 as X each has 5 element and every S element is in exactly 10 X sets. Now, we can see that every element of S is in 4 Y. means 10 elements in S, a total of 40 in Y. Now each Y has 2 element, so total no of Y sets must be 40 / 2 = 20. Is this correct?

Comment: The given question is taken from NCERT EXEMPLAR PROBLEMS CLASS IX, and the solution is n=20

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4154201/845875