# Find $n$ if each element of $\mathrm{S}$ belong to exactly 10 of the $\mathrm{X}_{r}^{\prime}$ 's and to exactly 4 of the $\mathrm{Y}_{r}^{\prime} s$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Each set $X$, contains 5 elements and each set $Y$, contains 2 element
and $\bigcup_{r=1}^{20} \mathrm{X}_{r}=\mathrm{S}=\bigcup_{r=1}^{n} \mathrm{Y}_{r}$. If each element of $\mathrm{S}$ belong to exactly 10 of the $\mathrm{X}_{r}^{\prime}$ 's and to
exactly 4 of the $\mathrm{Y}_{r}^{\prime} s$, then $n$ is

(A) 10
(B) 20
(C) 100
(D) 50

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327379/what-is-meaning-of-big-u-in-sets#comment8601444_1327379

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is (B)
Since, $n\left(\mathrm{X}_{r}\right)=5, \bigcup_{r=1}^{20} \mathrm{X}_{r}=\mathrm{S}$, we get $n(\mathrm{~S})=100$
But each element of $\mathrm{S}$ belong to exactly 10 of the $\mathrm{X}$ 's
So, $\frac{100}{10}=10$ are the number of distinct elements in $\mathrm{S}$.
Also each element of $S$ belong to exactly 4 of the $Y_{r}^{\prime} s$ and each $Y$, contain 2 elements. If $S$ has $n$ number of $Y$, in it. Then, which gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{2 n}{4} &=10 \\
n &=20
\end{aligned}
$$